# How can I use `liftIO` with State to print values inside that Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to print inside the `State` monad by using `liftIO` function from `MonadIO` class:

```hs
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

import Control.Applicative

facHelper :: Integer -> State Integer ()
facHelper 0 = pure ()
facHelper n = do
  currentState <- get
  liftIO $ putStrLn $ "n = " ++ show currentState
  modify (*n)
  facHelper (n-1)

factorial :: Integer -> Integer
factorial n = snd (runState (facHelper n) 1)

main :: IO ()
main = print $ factorial 6
```

However, I get the error:

> No instance for (MonadIO Data.Functor.Identity.Identity) arising from a use of ‘liftIO’

If I look up [`MonadIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.3.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) class:

I see an instance:

```hs
MonadIO m => MonadIO (StateT s m)
```

And also see that `State s` is a type alias

```hs
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

So, in principle, I could use `liftIO` with `State`. Where is the problem ?

Comment: If you ever end up with a term (like `factorial 6`) that you want to do `IO`, but whose type doesn't mention `IO` anywhere (like `Integer`), you know you've screwed up. There is a sense in which the entire *point* of the `IO` family of types is that it can't be escaped.

Comment: If you are doing this for temporary debugging purposes, check out `Debug.Trace` instead. You can do `traceM $ "n = " ++ show currentState` to help debug logic in any monad without having to modify it to use IO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do `IO`, then `IO` has to be at the bottom of your monad transformer stack. Here's the usual `mtl`-way of fixing things:

```
facHelper :: (MonadIO m, MonadState Integer m) => Integer -> m ()
-- same definition as before

factorial :: Integer -> IO Integer
factorial n = execStateT (facHelper n) 1

main :: IO ()
main = factorial 6 >>= print
```

This uses `StateT Integer IO` instead of `State Integer` (i.e. `StateT Integer Identity`).

If you're curious about the mechanical details of what went wrong with your approach:

1. want `MonadIO (State s)`
2. have `type State s = StateT s Identity`, therefore want `MonadIO (StateT s Identity)`
3. have `MonadIO m => MonadIO (StateT s m)`, and more specifically have `MonadIO Identity => MonadIO (StateT s Identity)`, therefore want `MonadIO Identity`
4. don't (and can't sensibly) have `MonadIO Identity`

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel ! When you say, "If you want to do IO, then IO has to be at the bottom of your monad transformer stack." what do you mean by "at the bottom" ?

Comment: @F.Zer It has to be the base monad that gets transformed (perhaps by many other transformers in sequence). In a stack like `FooT (BarT (BazT Quux)))`, `Quux` is the bottom of the stack.